# how to properly track thread in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

**Situation:**

I'm currently debugging an application which has many threads. I put a debugger points in my code, and at this points I know I have 10 threads and everything is fine. However on the 5 fifth step, my application crashes.

**Problem:**

I'd like to know if that is possible when my code is stop, to monitors every thread which make a step? So I can find which one cause the crash.

Comment: You might want to enable [Break on Exception Thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd(v=vs.140).aspx) so your program stops when the exception that causes the crash is thrown even if that code is inside a try-catch. EDIT: Updated link to 2015 instructions.

Comment: thanks!! it already throw exception and I see them, however it's a stack overflow exception... P.S. why updated to 2015 when I use 2013?

Comment: Because your original title of your question was "how to properly track thread in VStudio 2015?" but you tagged it 2013 then another user updated the tag to 2015, then Pressacco changed the tag and the title to 2013. [Here is the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.120).aspx) to the 2013 instructions

Comment: thanks for the link - my bad I didn't notice the 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2013 go to Debug > Windows > Threads (`Ctrl + Alt + H`) menu. This will open a window where you can see all threads. You can pause threads you want and execute what ever you want. hope this helps

Comment: The title of the question say 2015.  But the tag is 2013

Comment: Set a break point in your source code just before the location where the application freezes.  Then, as *GmailUser* mentioned, open the *Threads* window.  At this point if you want to trace through you code, consider freezing all of the threads (click on a thread an press *Pause* EXCEPT the one of interested in stepping through.  This will make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!! Works good. If I may ask a last question on this post, is there a way to see on which line is a specific thread at a given time?

Comment: re: StackOverflow exception, I would look to see if you have a recursive loop that is not terminating.  Is the same method/function being called over and over again?  Once you have selected a thread, take a look at the *Callstack* window.

Comment: Hmmm... here I have another problem, I'm calling a dll function (a dll for which I have access to code). But I have a wrapper to call those C++ function from C#. So I cannot see what happens in them...